# nodejs mssql package- how do I tell a sql syntax error from a server error like a timeout?

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am running mssql queries (using the nodejs mssql package) from strings. if the query fails how do I know if its a sql syntax error, or a server error (eg a timeout)? Examples of both types include:

Server error:

1. query `update x set y=1` err: `Error: operation timed out for an unknown reason`

Syntax error:

1. if mssql config is wrong: `ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'xxx'`
2. query `create database Logs` err: `RequestError: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'`
3. query `create databbbbbase Logs` error: `RequestError: Unknown object type 'databbbbbase' used in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER statement`

I am running the queries like this `await pool.request().query(querystring)` and using a catch block to get the error message.

Can I safely say if mssql error message is just 'Error' not a specific type (eg 'ConnectionError') that I should rerun the query?

Comment: What client library?

Comment: @DanielA.White whoops, updated post with: using the nodejs mssql package. Thanks for the reminder!